# Replacing input type=text.outerHTML() with new outerHTML() at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day, I am trying to replace the `outerHTML` of an input element with the `outerHTML` of a jQuery selector that is build up at runtime. The input element looks like:

```
<INPUT class=ajaxupload id=field_189 type=text value=001.JPG|/Accounts/documents/generic/379a30cc-26b9-4660-b9ac-8fbebe66c5dd.JPG>
```

The above element needs to be replaced with the following:

```
<SPAN class=ajaxUpload-container-parent id=field_189_container>
<SPAN class=ajaxUpload-container>
<A class=\"Buttons ajaxUpload-button\" id=field_189_button href=\"javascript:void(0);\">Upload File</A>
<INPUT name=ajaxfile class=ajaxUpload-file id=field_189_file style=\"ZOOM: 1; FILTER: alpha(opacity=0)\" type=file>
<INPUT name=field_189_hidden id=field_189_hidden type=hidden value=001.JPG|/Accounts/documents/generic/379a30cc-26b9-4660-b9ac-8fbebe66c5dd.JPG>
</SPAN>
```

The above snippet of code is the `outerHTML` of a jQuery selector.

I am trying the following: `element.outerHTML(newelement.outerHTML());`

My problem is that `element.outerHTML()` does not change.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is `.replaceWith()`:

```
var element = $('#field_189'),
    newelement = '<span class="ajaxUpload-container-parent" id="field_189_container"><span class="ajaxUpload-container"><a class="Buttons ajaxUpload-button" id="field_189_button" href="javascript:void(0);">Upload File</a><input name="ajaxfile" class="ajaxUpload-file" id="field_189_file" style="zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=0);" type="file"><input name="field_189_hidden" id="field_189_hidden" type="hidden" value="001.JPG|/Accounts/documents/generic/379a30cc-26b9-4660-b9ac-8fbebe66c5dd.JPG"></span>';

element.replaceWith(newelement);
```